# Error after trying to update custom columns

Tags: magento-1.9

Im trying to update a column, but no succces, im getting a error of:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract::update(), 1 passed in ..Model\Observer.php on line 76 and at least 2 expected in ..\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php:590 Stack trace: #0 ..\Model\Observer.php(76): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->update('UPDATE sales_fl...')
```

Here is my code, dont understand what is wrong with it:

```
  $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
        $themeTable = $resource->getTableName('sales_flat_order');

       $order = $observer->getEvent()->getCreditmemo()->getOrder();

        $sql1 = "UPDATE " . $themeTable . " SET finance_invoice_url = 'teste' WHERE entity_id = ".$order->getId();//update
        $writeConnection->update($sql1);
```

Following the link example online:

```
$writeConnection->update(
            $themeTable,
            array("finance_invoice_url" => "teste", "finance_invoice_id" => 2),
            "entity_id =".$order->getId()
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try update query from this link. It should work.

http://www.codexpedia.com/magento/magento-direct-mysql-query-for-create-read-update-and-delete/

Comment: I did, after checking your example i updated by code to like this:
`code` $writeConnection->update(
            $themeTable,
            array("magnifinance_invoice_url" => "teste", "magnifinance_invoice_id" => 2),
            $order->getId()
        ); `code`   but no success

Comment: Issue at last in query. Please update entity_id=$order->getId()

Comment: Writing from mobile so may be syntax is wrong so please correct it before implement.

Comment: updated my answer, but still didnt update

Comment: What error your are getting while runing this updated script?

Comment: thats the thing, i dont get any error

Comment: Please chec suggested edit by me and try

Answer (score 0):

```
$writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
$themeTable = $resource->getTableName('sales_flat_order');
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getCreditmemo()->getOrder();
$sql1 = "UPDATE " . $themeTable . " SET magnifinance_invoice_url = 'teste' WHERE entity_id = ".$order->getId(); //update
$writeConnection->query($sql1);
```

Let me know if not working

Comment: Is not working, just test it

Comment: Can you please do echo the sql1 and run same query into mysql if run then your query is right

Comment: Hello Sunil, i just ran the query into mysql and it updated. Also when echo the sql1 gave me "UPDATE sales_flat_order SET magnifinance_invoice_url = 'teste 2' WHERE entity_id = 25"

Comment: Can you put try and catch around and check what is error

Comment: TeamViewer possible?

Comment: i added you skpe